# If condition of Update Trigger of SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

If I have a table called **Task** with the following columns in it:

- Id
- Name
- Project (varchar)
- PercentComplete (int)
- Userstamp
- Timestamp

The table has a view. The view has similar columns as the Task table except for **PercentComplete** (int). Instead it has **Completed** (bit).

The view has a trigger for update. Here is a snippet from the update trigger of a view

```
IF 
    UPDATE (Completed)

BEGIN
    UPDATE Task
    SET PercentComplete = CASE Completed
            WHEN 1
                THEN 100
            ELSE 0
            END
        ,Userstamp = inserted.Userstamp
        ,Timestamp = getDate()
    FROM inserted
END
```

This works as expected. However now I need to add a condition for the Project column.

For example, only update the table if the Project = 'MyProject'. So something like:

```
IF 
    UPDATE (Completed) and inserted.Project = 'MyProject'

BEGIN
    UPDATE Task
    SET PercentComplete = CASE Completed
            WHEN 1
                THEN 100
            ELSE 0
            END
        ,Userstamp = inserted.Userstamp
        ,Timestamp = getDate()
    FROM inserted
END
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Tip: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement.  (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I agree this is a horrible way of getting the job done, but I'm dealing with a lot of legacy code, so unfortunately I gotta live with it till I get an  opportunity to refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is an inner join and a simple where case.

```
UPDATE T
SET PercentComplete = CASE Completed
        WHEN 1 THEN 100
        ELSE 0
    END
    ,Userstamp = inserted.Userstamp
    ,Timestamp = getDate()
FROM Task AS T
INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I
    ON I.ID = T.ID
WHERE I.Project = 'Your Project'
```